# Fontspec warning : "rename-feature-not-exist"

Tags: xetex, fontspec, xepersian

I want to use `Xepersian` package. But I get this error while compiling with Xelatex.

> fontspec warning : "rename-feature-not-exist"

Can some one help me with this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}
آزمایش
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to have been reported on the [`fontspec` development page](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/148) but no action or comments have been made. It's only a warning and not an error, and should only affect you if you wish to use the Persian names for `fontspec` features.  I would just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks @AlanMunn . I check the errors and the reason that I cannot compile ye persian document is due to this error:


xepersian.sty
662
Undefined control sequence.
l.662 \if@extrafootnotefeatures

Comment: @m.akbari But this is a different error. You need to try to construct a Minimal Working Example that shows the problem. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for some information on how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

The warning seems to reflect an issue that  has been reported on the [fontspec development page](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/148) but no action or comments have been made. It's only a warning and not an error, and should only affect you if you wish to use the Persian names for fontspec features, and in particular the `Renderer` (تحویل دهنده.) feature. I would just ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this warning is that in version 2.2b of `fontspec-xetex.sty`, there was

```
\keys_define:nn {fontspec-preparse} {
  Renderer .choice_code:n = {
    \fontspec_update_fontid:n {+rend:\l_keys_choice_tl}
    \int_compare:nTF {\l_keys_choice_int < 3} {
      \tl_set:Nv \l_fontspec_renderer_tl
        { g_fontspec_renderer_tag_ \l_keys_choice_tl }
    }{
      \fontspec_warning:nx {only-luatex-feature} {Renderer=Full/Basic}
    }
  }
  ,
  Renderer .generate_choices:n = {AAT,ICU,Graphite,Full,Basic}
}
```

But the key `fontspec-preparse` was changed into `fontspec-renderer` in version 2.3:

```
\keys_define:nn {fontspec-renderer}
 {
  Renderer .choice_code:n =
   {
    \fontspec_update_fontid:n {+rend:\l_keys_choice_tl}
    \int_compare:nTF {\l_keys_choice_int <= 3} {
      \tl_set:Nv \l_fontspec_renderer_tl
        { g_fontspec_renderer_tag_ \l_keys_choice_tl }
     }
     {
      \fontspec_warning:nx {only-luatex-feature} {Renderer=Full/Basic}
     }
   }
  ,
  Renderer .generate_choices:n = {AAT,ICU,Graphite,Full,Basic}
 }
```

and this change of name was not reflected in the definition of the macro `\aliasfontfeature` and so one would get that warning.

I have patched fontspec in version 13.9 of `xepersian` package to fix this and also sent the fix to Will.

I also provided a fix for this on [`fontspec` issue page](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/148).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A bit more detail, a minimal example using the patch, and/or a link to the patch source would help improve this answer. Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: Very sorry for the slow fix to this problem `:(` Will address ASAP. One reason for my slowness is because I think there's a better way to do this through `l3keys` and I wanted to take the time to investigate…

Comment: @WillRobertson: There was no need for apologies; When you fix this, please let me know so that I remove my patch from `xepersian`. Thanks.